# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

Вот файл appsettings.json:`{

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EmployeeAppCon": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EmployeeDB;Trusted_Connection=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}`
```

Я хочу сделать Web Api что би добавлять задания и дата до которой я должен исполнить ее.
Когда запускаю проект,вилетает ексепшн System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Вот еще файл DepartmentController.cs:

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public DepartmentController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            string query = @"
                     seleсt DepartmentID, DepartmentName from dbo.Department";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon=new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(table);
        }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: В слове `seleсt` буква `с` - русская.

Comment: Чел ти гений, спасибо